# PHPStorm Is throwing an error when trying to run phpcs

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I am trying to run the PHP CodeSniffer, but I get an error.

```
PHP Code Sniffer
phpcs: Can not correctly run the tool with parameters:
C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/___0.tmp/Foo.class.php
--standard=PSR2
--encoding=utf-8
--report=xml
Possible tool process hangup after 5 sec.
```

I think it has to do with the file location. My files are not in Temp. However, I see no place to set a default folder

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: @Volatil3 I have not found a solution for this, but my needs have changed a bit. I should check if this is still applicable for the current version of PHPStorm. Have you had this problem as well?

Comment: Facing same issue, yeah

Answer (score 7):

You need to increase timeout value.

Go to `Settings/Preferences` - `Languages & Frameworks` - `PHP` - `Code Sniffer` and change/add configuration for the tool. You can set *tool process timeout* up to 30 seconds.

[image: Code sniffer timeout]

Comment: Additionally, you may need to increase PHP's script memory limit.

    memory_limit = 256M